# I need to display a simple AlertDialog within a called class

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I'm very new to Android, and have a basic question.  I need at certain points to display a user notification in a dialog box, which they can simply acknowledge with the OK button.

I'm using:

```
   myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("My message");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

This works well in the Main program, but within a called method it needs the Activity and the Context from the main program.  Can anybody tell me how to pass these?  getApplicationContext() seems to be acceptable, but I can't figure out how to pass the Activity.

Better still of course would be to get the parent Context and Activity within the method, but I can't get that to work either.

I'd be grateful for any help.

-**update 10/07/21**

Rahul has given me the solution to the problem I posed: how to pass in the Activity and Context.

The problem is that the dialog still doesn't show.
I found a variation online as follows:

```
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
            builder.setTitle("Alert")
                    .setMessage("My message")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

but this doesn't work either.

I'm puzzled that such a common and simple task needs so much code.  In the desktop languages I'm used to it can be done in a single line.

So my titled question stands, but can anyone see where the code is faulty?
Many thanks

Comment: Where are you calling the class?

Comment: It should be great if you can show us bits of your code you are using on a GitHub repo.

Comment: The main program displays an editbox and a button. The user types in a value and clicks the button. I then create an instance and call a method within it to handle the value. Something like: MyObj myobj = new MyObj(); myobj.myMethod(myValue);  I want to show the AlertDialog within the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass activity to the class when initializing the object or you can pass activity when calling the function.

### Case 1 (Recommended)

Pass Activity when calling the function:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.showDialog(myValue, ActivityName.this);
```

Where function will look like this:

```
public void showDialog(int myValue, Activity activity){
  ...
}
```

Then you can use this activity instance inside the method.

### Case 2

Pass Activity when initializing the object:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj(ActivityName.this);
```

Where Class will look like this:

```
class MyObj{
  private Activity thisActivity;
  public MyObj(Activity activity){
      thisActivity = Activity;
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you can use this activity instance.

> When you have activity object available you can replace context object with it.

Comment: You can typecast context to activity but there are two type of contexts: application context and activity context you have to sure which one you are using otherwise your code will yield some error.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the detailed help.  I did as you said and it all compiled OK, but when I ran the app through the emulator the screen went completely black.  I tried again and got the message "System UI isn't responding" Do you have any idea why?

Comment: This kind issue occurs when UI thread is blocked for some reason for a longer time.